# Configure u-blox GPS module from serial port

Tags: python, serial, gps

My teacher gave me an u-blox M8N GPS that he bought from Banggood, and he wants me to do 2/3 things:

1. Change baud rate to 115200
2. Change measure rate to 10 kHz
3. Integrate GPS with `gpsd`

My doubt here is: I know how to change baud rate and measure rate in u-center (u-blox software) but only exists for Windows. From here what I need to know is:

I can change GPS configuration by sending hexadecimal data to GPS, like this:

[image: Message structure from m8n documentation]

I have the GPS module connected to UART pins in the Raspberry Pi.

1. First problem

**How can I do this in python? How can I "build" hexadecimal messages in Python and how can I send them to GPS module?**

2. Second Problem

**How do I properly set up `gpsd` on a Raspberry Pi?**

Comment: I have used the u-blox software on a PC and it works.  But for the Pi I found a better way.  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68816/how-can-i-set-up-my-g-mouse-usb-gps-for-use-with-raspbian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1. You work through a Python tutorial and use the Python serial module.

Problem 2. You read the documentation for gpsd.

Comment: `gpsd` is not suitable to configure the device mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

while using windows might not an option for you `u-center` is the easy way to get done.

what i do recommend in general is to have a quick search on [github](http://github.com/) first and see if something comes up.

searching for 'ublox' the result includes [pyUblox](https://github.com/tridge/pyUblox) which lacks a `README` file but the *code* should help to get you started.

in case you'd like to have a more generic introduction to working with hexadecimal values in python i do recommend consulting the **stackexchange.com** cosmos, i.e. [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678132/python-hexadecimal) as your question is not specific to raspberry pi.

Answer (score 0):

https://emlid.com/navio-ublox-ucenter/ there is a python script on that page that allows you to connect to u-center over ip with a UART connected gps if you you modify the script to catch the data you might be able to do what you want

Comment: actually GPS connected over spi

Comment: its a c program

Comment: Why do you correct your answer by adding comments? Why not actually edit your answer? Comments may be deleted without warning

Comment: nice find @ethanJohnston but it does require windows.